# What kind of data structure to use?

Tags: c#, oop, data-structures

I am working on a project where I need to keep track of:

- 5-6 Root items of just a string name
- Each root item need to have multiple children of different identifier types (int, string, float, etc). All the children of one root will be the same type but each root will have different children types
- user will need to be able to add/delete children from each root
- i will later need to access each children individually and perform string manipulations and parsing when needed

I've thought about maybe using a dictionary where the Key is a string and Values are lists of objects. Or having a unique class for each root item and each class will include a List of children.

Does anyone have any good suggestions? I'm still quite new to OOP, please bear with me :)

Thanks!

Comment: At first glance, a Dictionary<string, List<T>> seems like what you're looking for.

Comment: Do you want to *enforce* that all children of a given root are the same type? I'm struggling to find a way to do that. If you are willing to live without that level of type enforcement, a `Dictionary<string, List<object>>` would work.

Comment: children of a given root doesn't have to be the same type, in fact it may be better if they are not. so with tuples, I will be able to dynamically add/delete items of which ever type I want?

Comment: My first glance isn't right - jonnyGold's solution is quick and elegant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public interface IRoot {}

public class RootItem<T> : IRoot
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<T> Children {get; set; }
}
```

And then keep a `Dictionary<string, IRoot>` to hold them all.

```
Dictionary<string, IRoot> hair = new Dictionary<string, IRoot>();
hair.Add(
  new RootItem<int>()
      {
        Name = "None",
        Children = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4}
      }
);

hair.Add(
  new RootItem<decimal>()
      {
        Name = "None",
        Children = new List<decimal>() {1m, 2m, 3m, 4m}
      }
);
```

Comment: Thanks.  For the record, @FishBasketGordo provided a much more fleshed-out sample.

Comment: `Dictionary<string, RootItem>` isn't valid because `RootItem` without the generic argument is an incomplete type.

Comment: Good point.  I missed that.  I use Visual Studio to write these code samples.

Comment: still not quite right... you cannot construct a `Dictionary<string, RootItem<T>>` -- you have to give it a concrete type, and then all or your child lists are now the same type.

Comment: But now, you can only have children of one type T.

Answer (score 2):

How about a generic class with a `List<T>` to contain the children:

```
public class Root<T>
{
    private List<T> children = null;

    public Root(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<T> Children
    {
        get
        {
            if (children == null)
            {
                children = new List<T>();
            }

            return children;
        }
    }
}

Root<int> intRoot = new Root<int>("IntRoot");
intRoot.Children.Add(23);
intRoot.Children.Add(42);

Root<string> stringRoot = new Root<string>("StringRoot");
stringRoot.Children.Add("String1");
stringRoot.Children.Add("String2");
stringRoot.Children.Add("String3");
stringRoot.Children.Add("String4");
```

If you want to hold all the roots in one object, you could write your own class or use a `Tuple`:

```
var rootGroup = Tuple.Create(intRoot, stringRoot);
// intRoot is accessible as rootGroup.Item1
// stringRoot is accessible as rootGroup.Item2
```

Comment: This is what I came up with but the OP also wants a `Dictionary<string, RootItem>` which I don't think is possible; you could have a base non-generic `RootItem` class but you'd lose some type safety in the process...

Comment: sorry for my lack of programming knowledge!
so when you declared intRoot and stringRoot, on the right hand side of the equal sign, are you basically calling the Root(string name) function? or.. is the Root(string name) "thing" in your class considered to constructor?

Comment: It's a constructor. Any time you see the `new` operator, you're dealing with a constructor. Also, you can tell it's a constructor by looking at the class itself, because it is named the same as the class and it doesn't have an explicit return type.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `Dictionary<string, Tuple<type1, type 2, etc>>` is a good candidate.

The key will be the string(root). The children to the root is a Tuple. We can add items to tuple. Thanks for pointing thisout.

[Good starting point on Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)

Comment: you cannot add or remove items from a tuple at runtime.

Comment: The `Tuple<T1, T2, ...>` construct allows for heterogeneous `Dictionary` values, but @swifferclean mentions that each value would be an arbitrary list whose items are each of the same type.  Its the type of the value lists that needs to vary.

Comment: hm.. i see. So it may be better to use a List<>? i think you could add and delete items from a list during runtime right..?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to go about it. There's a lot of casting that needs to happen, but it gets the job done:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, IRootCollection> values = new Dictionary<string, IRootCollection>();

        values["strings"] = new RootCollection<string>();
        (values["strings"] as RootCollection<string>).Add("foo");
        (values["strings"] as RootCollection<string>).Add("bar");

        values["ints"] = new RootCollection<int>();
        (values["ints"] as RootCollection<int>).Add(45);
        (values["ints"] as RootCollection<int>).Add(86);
    }

    interface IRootCollection { }
    class RootCollection<T> : List<T>, IRootCollection { }
```