# Storing disparate generics in a single enumerable

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance

Given a generic attribute class:

```
public class Attribute<T>
{
  string Name { get; set; }
  T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to have an object that contains an enumerable containing various types of that generic (for example int, string, datetime).

```
public class AttributableObject
{
  IEnumerable<???> attributes { get; set;}
}
```

Is there anyway to do this that won't run into variance problems?

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856497/what-kind-of-data-structure-to-use/10856583#10856583). It looks at a similar idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typical approach is to have the generic class derive from a non-generic base class (or interface,) and then have an enumerable of that type:

```
public abstract class AttributeBase
{
    // Non-generic stuff here
}

public class Attribute<T> : AttributeBase
{
    // Generic stuff here
}
```

Then you can declare:

```
IEnumerable<AttributeBase> attributes;
```

Of course you'll still need to know what the type of each element is if you'd like to use any of the generic features (like actually getting the value.)

Note that covariance/contravariance won't help here, since the `Value` property is both settable and gettable, and thus the generic parameter is invariant (not to mention that it's a generic *class*, so it can't be made co/contra-variant anyway.)

Comment: The problem is that in that situation there is no way for me to access the generic properties, Value in my original object, when I am trying to work with them.

Comment: @Matt you can cast/unbox them to their *more derived* version.

Comment: @dlev I was trying to avoid a gigantic switch statement essentially. The Attributes are being persisted to different tables in a database via EF. I was looking for a reasonable way to do this without having to scatter a bunch of code in a few locations everytime I want to allow a new type of attribute.